# Counting XML based on date conditionals with xslt

Tags: xslt, date, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm working with xslt for the first time. I have 2.0, but that's about the only advantage I have access to with the c# transform library we have. I'm trying to count a number of child nodes in the XML document which contain a date more than 12 years ago and have a certain type attribute.

Sample xml structure:

```
<xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<... />
<Dependents>
<Dependent><DOB>1964-04-01</DOB><DependentType>Spouse</DependentType></Dependent>
<Dependent><DOB>2000-01-01</DOB><DependentType>Child</DependentType></Dependent>
<Dependent><DOB>2012-01-01</DOB><DependentType>Child</DependentType></Dependent>
</Dependents>
<... />
```

where `<... />` signifies some extra unrelated stuff.

So essentially, I want the number of children younger than 12 years old. (I have the count of dependenttype = child of all ages working, it's just the under 12 that's giving me trouble). The approach that was suggested to me was to construct a variable that stands for 12 years ago from today and use that as a basis for comparison in the `count()` function. That sounds reasonable, but I'm stuck constructing the date without the use of 3rd party libraries (e.g. exslt) that are so often linked in questions like this for the easy, handy-dandy answers.

The xslt I've gotten so far for this is:

```
<xsl:variable name="today" select="current-dateTime()" as="xs:dateTime" />
<xsl:variable name="twelveyearsago" select="xs:dateTime(concat(year-from-dateTime($today) - 12, '-', month-from-dateTime($today), '-', day-from-dateTime($today)))" />
<xsl:text>12yearsago=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$twelveyearsago" />
```

And it's not working because the month-from-dateTime (and presumable day-from-dateTime) don't add leading zeros. For today, March 21 2012 I'm getting back: Saxon.Api.DynamicError : Invalid dateTime value "2000-3-21" (Month must be two digits) (The [W3Schools xpath function reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#datetime) implies that they *should*, but they don't.)

What I would like to output is:

```
<xsl:text>&amp;numberofchildren=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(//InsuranceRequest/HealthInsurance/Dependents/Dependent/DependentType[text() = 'Child'])" />
<xsl:text>&amp;childrenunder12=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="children under twelve" />
```

The more I pound my head against this, the more I feel like there's a simpler approach that I'm just not seeing.

Edit: I cleaned up the  xslt syntax so it's valid and not a doubly-quoted c# string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply substract a [duration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dt-yearMonthDuration) of 12 years as in `<xsl:variable name="twelveyearsago" select="$today - xs:yearMonthDuration('P12Y')"/>`, then use e.g. `//Dependent[DependentType = 'Child' and xs:date(DOB) >= $twelveyearsago]`.

[edit]
Here is a template that compiles and executes fine for with Saxon 9.4:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="today" select="current-date()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="twelve-years-ago" select="$today - xs:yearMonthDuration('P12Y')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//Dependent[DependentType = 'Child' and xs:date(DOB) >= $twelve-years-ago])"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The `yearMonthDuration` is working nicely, although I swear it wasn't working earlier... stupid syntax error on my part, no doubt. However, I don't think `DependedType = 'Child'` is correct, I think it needs to reference the text() somehow. At least, it's not working as you wrote it. I'm trying a few things now, but any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want you can use `//Dependent[DependentType/text() = 'Child']` but what I suggested is sufficient and in my view more commonly used. Selecting text nodes explicitly is only needed when dealing with mixed content. If you still have problems in getting something to work then post minimal but complete as well as usable code samples, then I am sure we can fix it. But I am not in the mood to try to work your C# strings into XML documents just to convince you that `DependentType = 'Child'` is working code. The only problem I see is your `DependedType = 'Child'` which has a typo or wrong name.

Comment: You were right that this `count(//Dependents/Dependent[DependentType = 'Child']` works. But I can't get this `count(//Dependents/Dependent[xs:date(DOB) >= $twelveyearsago])` to work. Sorry about the typo.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think the error you get is you can't compare `xs:date` to `xs:dateTime`, the easiest way to fix that is to use `current-date()` instead of `current-dateTime()` for your `today` variable. I will edit my post with a sample I tested with Saxon.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I had just discovered it and was trying to turn DOB into a dateTime instead of the far simpler fix you suggested. Also discovered we're using Saxon 9.2 and I was trying to figure out where it dumped the exact errors. Anyways, thanks a lot!